# Does "preguntó por" mean "ask about" or "ask for"?

Tags: traducción, definiciones

> Me
>   contó que no había visto a Delgadina desde hacía más de un mes, que parecía tan
>   repuesta del susto de mis estropicios que ni siquiera habló de ellos ni preguntó por
>   mí, y estaba muy contenta en un nuevo empleo, más cómodo y mejor pagado que
>   coser botones.  (Memorias de mis putas tristes, Garcia Marquez)

Edith Grossman translated this paragraph as follows:

> She  told  me  she  hadn't 
>   seen  Delgadina  for  more  than  a  month,  that  the  girl  seem ed  to  have  recovered  so  well  from  her  fright  at  my 
>   destructiveness that she didn't even  mention  it or **ask  for  me**, and  was  very  happy  in a  new job,  more comfortable 
>   and  better-paid  than  sewing  on  buttons.

Thus, I guess, "ask for me" for "preguntó por mí". However, I think the narrator in the novel meant that the girl did not ask *about* him, rather than *for* him. So, which one is correct here?

Answer (score 6):

Rather interesting question. In this context where two people are just catching up with each other, *preguntar por alguien* just means that you are also interested in catching up with other person who is absent from the conversation. It is a mean to show interest about the wellness of that other person. A typical conversation in which a person ask about a third party would be like this:

> Fulano: - Oye, ¿y qué tal le va a [Zutano](http://dle.rae.es/?id=cZGeuK3)?
>
> Mengano: - Ah, pues bien, ahora trabaja de chef en un restaurante.

In that conversation, Fulano *pregunta [a Mengano] por Zutano*.

Answer (score 3):

*ask for someone* can be also interpreted as *pedir saber de alguien*, which means *what's the other person doing* while not being present. (As the previous answer stated it.)

So we could have,

> (...) ni siquiera habló de ellos ni **pidió saber de mí**.

Answer (score 3):

In the context of this paragraph, you are correct, the author meant that the girl didn't asked *about* him.

In spanish **Preguntó por** would mean 'ask about' when the question is about information, and 'ask for' when the question is about objects or directions.